# Kivy Buildozer Android debug " # Command failed: ./distribute.sh -l"

Tags: android, debugging, ubuntu, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to make a apk with "buildozer android debug"  command. But When I write It I receive "   # Command failed: ./distribute.sh -l " problem. I coudnt find and answer to it.

```
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
  Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
Packages available for installation or update: 49
----------
id: 1 or "tools"
     Type: Tool
     Desc: Android SDK Tools, revision 24.0.2
----------
id: 2 or "platform-tools"
     Type: PlatformTool
     Desc: Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 20
----------
id: 3 or "build-tools-19.1.0"
     Type: BuildTool
     Desc: Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.1
----------
id: 4 or "build-tools-19.0.3"
     Type: BuildTool
     Desc: Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.3
----------
id: 5 or "build-tools-19.0.2"
     Type: BuildTool
     Desc: Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.2
----------
id: 6 or "build-tools-19.0.1"
     Type: BuildTool
     Desc: Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.1
----------
id: 7 or "build-tools-19.0.0"
     Type: BuildTool
     Desc: Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19
----------
id: 8 or "build-tools-18.1.1"
     Type: BuildTool
     Desc: Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1.1
----------
id: 9 or "build-tools-18.1.0"
     Type: BuildTool
     Desc: Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1
----------
id: 10 or "build-tools-18.0.1"
     Type: BuildTool
     Desc: Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.0.1
----------
id: 11 or "build-tools-17.0.0"
     Type: BuildTool
     Desc: Android SDK Build-tools, revision 17
----------
id: 12 or "doc-19"
     Type: Doc
     Desc: Documentation for Android SDK, API 19, revision 2
----------
id: 13 or "android-19"
     Type: Platform
     Desc: Android SDK Platform 4.4.2
           Revision 3
----------
id: 14 or "android-18"
     Type: Platform
     Desc: Android SDK Platform 4.3
           Revision 2
----------
id: 15 or "android-17"
     Type: Platform
     Desc: Android SDK Platform 4.2.2
           Revision 2
----------
id: 16 or "android-16"
     Type: Platform
     Desc: Android SDK Platform 4.1.2
           Revision 4
----------
id: 17 or "android-15"
     Type: Platform
     Desc: Android SDK Platform 4.0.3
           Revision 3
----------
id: 18 or "android-14"
     Type: Platform
     Desc: Android SDK Platform 4.0
           Revision 3
----------
id: 19 or "android-13"
     Type: Platform
     Desc: Android SDK Platform 3.2, revision 1
----------
id: 20 or "android-12"
     Type: Platform
     Desc: Android SDK Platform 3.1, revision 3
----------
id: 21 or "android-11"
     Type: Platform
     Desc: Android SDK Platform 3.0, revision 2
----------
id: 22 or "android-10"
     Type: Platform
     Desc: Android SDK Platform 2.3.3._r2
           Revision 2
----------
id: 23 or "android-9"
     Type: Platform
     Desc: Android SDK Platform 2.3.1_r2
           Revision 2 (Obsolete)
----------
id: 24 or "android-8"
     Type: Platform
     Desc: Android SDK Platform 2.2_r3
           Revision 3
----------
id: 25 or "android-7"
     Type: Platform
     Desc: Android SDK Platform 2.1_r3
           Revision 3
----------
id: 26 or "android-6"
     Type: Platform
     Desc: Android SDK Platform 2.0.1_r1
           Revision 1 (Obsolete)
----------
id: 27 or "android-5"
     Type: Platform
     Desc: Android SDK Platform 2.0, revision 1
----------
id: 28 or "android-4"
     Type: Platform
     Desc: Android SDK Platform 1.6_r2
           Revision 3
----------
id: 29 or "android-3"
     Type: Platform
     Desc: Android SDK Platform 1.5_r3
           Revision 4
----------
id: 30 or "android-2"
     Type: Platform
     Desc: Android SDK Platform 1.1_r1
           Revision 1 (Obsolete)
----------
id: 31 or "sample-19"
     Type: Sample
     Desc: Samples for SDK API 19, revision 5
----------
id: 32 or "sample-18"
     Type: Sample
     Desc: Samples for SDK API 18, revision 1
----------
id: 33 or "sample-17"
     Type: Sample
     Desc: Samples for SDK API 17, revision 1
----------
id: 34 or "sample-16"
     Type: Sample
     Desc: Samples for SDK API 16, revision 1
----------
id: 35 or "sample-15"
     Type: Sample
     Desc: Samples for SDK API 15, revision 2
----------
id: 36 or "sample-14"
     Type: Sample
     Desc: Samples for SDK API 14, revision 2
----------
id: 37 or "sample-13"
     Type: Sample
     Desc: Android SDK Samples for Android API 13, revision 1
----------
id: 38 or "sample-12"
     Type: Sample
     Desc: Android SDK Samples for Android API 12, revision 1
----------
id: 39 or "sample-11"
     Type: Sample
     Desc: Android SDK Samples for Android API 11, revision 1
----------
id: 40 or "sample-10"
     Type: Sample
     Desc: Android SDK Samples for Android API 10, revision 1
----------
id: 41 or "sample-9"
     Type: Sample
     Desc: Android SDK Samples for Android API 9, revision 1
----------
id: 42 or "sample-8"
     Type: Sample
     Desc: Android SDK Samples for Android API 8, revision 1
----------
id: 43 or "sample-7"
     Type: Sample
     Desc: Android SDK Samples for Android API 7, revision 1
----------
id: 44 or "source-19"
     Type: Source
     Desc: Sources for Android SDK, API 19, revision 2
----------
id: 45 or "source-18"
     Type: Source
     Desc: Sources for Android SDK, API 18, revision 1
----------
id: 46 or "source-17"
     Type: Source
     Desc: Sources for Android SDK, API 17, revision 1
----------
id: 47 or "source-16"
     Type: Source
     Desc: Sources for Android SDK, API 16, revision 2
----------
id: 48 or "source-15"
     Type: Source
     Desc: Sources for Android SDK, API 15, revision 2
----------
id: 49 or "source-14"
     Type: Source
     Desc: Sources for Android SDK, API 14, revision 1

# Android packages installation done.
# Check application requirements
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -l
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# If the error is not obvious, please raise the log_level to 2
# and retry the latest command.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Do you know what may cause this problem? Thank you for your help

Comment: I raised to log_level =2 but problem remains still.

Comment: Post the log with log_level 2, it's to provide information to people trying to help you.

Comment: @NecdetCanKeleş raising log_level to 2 actually provides more info with more verbosity. it's not gonna solve anything by itself. set log_level to 2 and show us the output